# Populate part of several columns of a data frame with values from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have two dataframes that look something like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"),
                  Value1 = c(1, 7, 9, 4, 2, 2, 3, 6),
                  Value2 = c(7, 2, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1),
                  Value3 = c(3, 6, 2, 2, 8, 1, 9, 1)) 

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"),
                  Value1 = c(2, 7, 8, 3, 6, 5, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  Value2 = c(6, 2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  Value3 = c(4, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I would like to populate `df2` with corresponding `Value1`, `Value2` and `Value3` based on matching `ID`, while still keeping the rows that already have values for IDs A-H. I have written the following code but it's incomplete as I'm not sure how to fill in the rest of the terms in the ifelse() function. Could someone help me with completing that or if there is a better way of doing this?

```
df2 <- ifelse(df1$ID %in% df2$ID, ?, ?)
```

The result I'm looking for looks something like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"),
                  Value1 = c(2, 7, 8, 3, 6, 5, 0, 1, 1, 7, 9, 4, 2, 2, 3, 6),
                  Value2 = c(6, 2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1),
                  Value3 = c(4, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 6, 2, 2, 8, 1, 9, 1))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`rows_update()` modifies existing rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  rows_update(df1, by = "ID")
```